# No module name celery with uWSGI and Python3

Tags: python, celery, uwsgi

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fb_archive/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "./fb_archive/celery.py", line 5, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: No module named 'celery'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

uWGSI says `No module name celery`.
It works well without uWGSI.
I use python 3.5 and virtualenv.

I test with python 2.7 and uWGSI, it can load celery.
How can I load celery with python 3.x?

This is my celery.py.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'fb_archive.settings')

app = Celery('fb_archive')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',
)

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.cache:CacheBackend',
)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

And this is my **init**.py.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

Comment: I think we would need to see some source code to be able to help more...

Comment: @jeyoor, Thany, you! I add celery.py and __init__.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use uwsgi for python3.X**

if you want to run django in python3.X (virtualenv) with uwsgi, then uwsgi must be installed in python3.X virtualenv, i guess you are running python2.7 uwsgi without virtualenv. You need to remove your installation of uwsgi and then reinstall uwsgi in your virtualenv for python3.X, then it will include celery when you run uwsgi from within virtualenv.

Follow these steps:

- remove uwsgi
  `sudo pip uninstall uwsgi`
- go into the project directory
- activate your virtual env
  `source venv/bin/activate`
- fresh install uwsgi in activated virtualenv`pip install uwsgi`
- now run your django project using ini file `uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/sites/project.ini`
- if you get any permission denied on some file, just chown it `sudo chown <user> /path/to/file` or just do sudo.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you have celery installed for Python2.7 but not for Python3. You can try installing it for Python3 using `pip3 install celery`.

It is also possible that you *do* have celery installed for Python3 in your normal environment, but that it's not installed in your virtualenv.

Comment: If you switch to a new virtualenv, I think you'll need to reinstall celery for python3 in that virtualenv as well...

Comment: I already installed pip3 install celery. I tried to install python 3.4 in my was, it works well. Does celery work under python3.4?

Comment: When you run `pip3 freeze | grep celery` what version do you get?